# How does a web server know what linked to it?

Tags: web-services, http

I use photobucket to post images to various user forums.  The forums I post to allow the embedding of a direct link to the image.

One of the services photobucket provides is a view history which includes not only number of hits but also information on which sites viewed the page.  I can't figure out how they do that -- can anyone fill me in on the details?

I would like to add that ability to my own server, but isn't this a security hole in the HTTP protocol of sorts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's usually information pulled from the [HTTP_Referrer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referrer). It can be removed/changed so it's not a foolproof thing for security but the very basic usage is to compare this and check where it came from. When you embed an image/object from elsewhere, the term is [Hot Linking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hotlinking) and this is what the technique will usually prevent.

Answer (score 3):

It knows what linked to it by the [HTTP referrer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referrer).
Any server side scripting language will have its own way of retrieving this information.

Answer (score 2):

When you request an image from that web service (lets say it's a PHP page), the image is served, but first PHP takes a look at the `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` variable to see what URL the request is coming from